# i am trying to print the secret key in aes algo. but the key size printed is not 128 bits

Tags: java, encryption, aes

print secret key

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(128);
SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
String plainText = "AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption";
System.out.println("Plain Text Before Encryption: " + plainText);

String encryptedText = encrypt(plainText, secretKey);
System.out.println("Encrypted Text After Encryption: " + encryptedText);

String decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedText, secretKey);
System.out.println("Decrypted Text After Decryption: " + decryptedText);
System.out.println("srecretkey"+secretKey);
```

The ouput i am getting is:

```
Plain Text Before Encryption: AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption
Encrypted Text After Encryption: l4YZj1SjqS/vr1mK9K4LC7lBFfQ4wkJg2zIlb81ghpkM5qnvCyyfMeYop2ppHDoX
Decrypted Text After Decryption: AES Symmetric Encryption Decryption
srecretkeyjavax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@15300
```

The size of key is not 128 bits here.

Comment: "the size of key is not 128 bits here" - are you assuming that "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@15300" is the actual secret key data? It's not. That's just the default output of `Object.toString()` if it's not overridden. I see no reason to think that the size of the key *isn't* 128 bits based on your output.

Comment: [`getEncoded()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded()) returns the raw key data (as `byte[]`), however, this data is 32 bytes (= 256 bits) in size, since this size was specified in [`init()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html#init(int)).

Comment: So how can i print the actual key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your question and code.

First: you are asking about a **128** bit AES key but your parameter for keygenerator is "256" that means you generate a **256** bit (= 32 byte) long AES key:

```
keyGenerator.init(256);
```

Second: an AES key is random data in a byte array that is not suitable for printing to a string. When you need a printout of the key there are several ways to to - I show you a way with encoding the key to a (Base64) encoded string:

```
String aesKeyBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aesKey);
```

This is the output of the sample program:

```
Generate a 256 bit = 32 byte long AES key
secretKey: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@1518c
aesKey length: 32
aesKey:[B@6d9c638
aesKeyBase64: cWEo4+jv0SXBgbiZbdiouasFYuV3rUYKQ3403y4wU14=
```

Below is the full code, run the example with my online compiler: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/SoGenerateAesKey#Main.java

```
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        System.out.println("Generate a 256 bit = 32 byte long AES key");
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(256);
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        System.out.println("secretKey: " + secretKey);
        // the key is a 32 bytes long byte array
        byte[] aesKey = secretKey.getEncoded();
        System.out.println("aesKey length: " + aesKey.length);
        System.out.println("aesKey:" + aesKey);
        // convert to a base64 encoded String
        String aesKeyBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aesKey);
        System.out.println("aesKeyBase64: " + aesKeyBase64);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

To get the secret key back from Base64 encoded string use this line of code:

```
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode("base64string"), "AES");
```

and use it as input for your cipher.init:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
```

Comment: but the aes key printed here is not 32 characters..could you please clear out that the aesKey printed should it be exactly of length 32 characters for 256bits aes

Comment: An AES key has nothing to do with "characters" but with bytes or better a 32 bytes long byte array. An AES key should be random and so it will contain a lot of bytes that are **not printable** as characters, instead you could use a hex-string output (will be 64 "characters" long as each byte is represented with 2 "characters") or - what is often more usefull - as a Base64-encoded string. Simply decode the Base64-string to get a 32 byte long byte array or use the key in "aesKey" directly (I used the base64-encoded form to get a printout.

Comment: Thanku for your help.. My program is working finally

Comment: I'm glad to read that your program is working now. If my answer was helpful please mark it as accepted, thanks.

Comment: i had one more question.how can i get back the aesKey back in its original format.as the datatype of the secret key is int

Comment: here you converted the secretkey to a string. how to convert it back to int

Comment: @Anchal Dobriyal: kindly see my edit for Base64-decoding and generate the SecretKeySpec from the key :-)

Comment: i am getting an error that secretkeyspec cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, SecretKey secretKey)
   throws Exception {
  Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
  byte[] encryptedTextByte = decoder.decode(encryptedText);
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
  byte[] decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextByte);
  String decryptedText = new String(decryptedByte);
  return decryptedText;

Comment: here instead of the SecretKey i want to use to aesKeybase64 key but when i used your code to decode this aeskeybase64 it is showing the error that secretkeyspec cannot be resolved to a type